# PHP simple form validation - help needed

Tags: php, validation

Ok, what I'm trying to achieve is a very simple form validation like the following.

1. Name: [required, min length: 2, max length: 255]
2. Email: [required, min length: 3, max length: 255, valid email format]
3. Date of Birth: [optional, format: dd/mm/yyyy]

However, once i click submit (either if the fields are empty or filled) I get all of my echoed errors displayed on a blank page.

**"name must be at least 2 charactersname is requiredemail must be at least 3 charactersinvalid emailemail cannot be left empty"**

My code so far:

*index.php*

```
<form method="post" action="confirm.php">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" />
email:<input type="text" name="email" />
DOB:<input type="date" name="dob" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and

*confirm.php*

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['$name'];
$email = $_POST['$email'];
$dob = $_POST['$dob'];

$namelen = strlen($email);
$emaillen = strlen($email);
$max = 255;
$minname = 2;
$minemail = 3;

if($namelen<$minname){
    echo"name must be at least 2 characters";
}
elseif($namelen>$max){
    echo"name must be less than 255 characters";
}

if(empty($name)){
    echo"name is required";
}
else{
    continue;
}

if($emaillen<$minemail){
    echo"email must be at least 3 characters";
}
elseif($emaillen>$max){
    echo"email must be less than 255 characters";
}

if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    continue;
}
else{
    echo"invalid email";
}

if(empty($email)){
    echo"email cannot be left empty";
}
else{
    continue;
}

?>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: there aren't alert() function in php, only in javascript, you should change for echo.

Comment: You are writing Js in php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

alert is a JavaScript function, not a PHP one. If you want to use an alert function in PHP, you'll need to create a custom one like so:

```
function alert($alertMessage){
    //Do something with $alertMessage
}
```

The error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function alert()

basically means that PHP could not find a function called alert.

Comment: Alright, I have changed all the alert("") into echo"", however, when I click submit now it sends me to a blank page echoing out all of my errors "name must be at least 2 charactersname is requiredemail must be at least 3 charactersinvalid emailemail cannot be left empty".

Answer (score 1):

lets do it your way,replace your alert with the following code and your code will exactly do what u want it to do :)

Replace

```
alert("email must be less than 255 characters");
```

with:

```
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('email must be less than 255 characters');
</script>";
```

Comment: hahahahaha, this is embarrassing. I edited my original post, I hope you can help me.

Comment: whats embarassing? u wanted to display alert box on error .this code will exactly do the same.

Comment: It's embarrassing because i mixed up alert and echo. Read my edited post, I have a bigger problem now.